# "Multiple desktops" missing from Workspace Behavior in KubuntuTrusty

Tags: multiple-desktops

I've just upgraded to Kubuntu Trusty.  There were some errors during the update which I did not understand, so I just plowed on and restarted.  Now I can't get multiple desktops.  More precisely, the "Workspace Behavior" section of System Settings does not include the  Virtual Desktops section at all.  I assume I'm missing some module or other -- but which one?

Answer (score 1):

you have to go into appearance and click on the "enable workspaces" checkbox.
hope it helps